# Private pod with static library in along with swift pod

Tags: ios, frameworks, static-libraries, cocoapods, private

I'm working on pods development for an iOS dev team (on private repo). My low-level C/Obj-C core pod contains a static library with some headers and is used as dependency in other pods (pushed with `--use-libraries`).

Now that the iOS team wants to integrate Swift pods, they had to add the `use_framework!` option in the Podfile of their projects. Of course, they obtained the following error during `pod install`  :

> The 'XXX' target has transitive dependencies that include static
>   binaries

I spent half a day on the web looking for a way to make my pods compatible with the `use_framework!` option, in vain. This is very frustrating, as Google Services pods are proofs that it's possible to bypass this problem in a clean way (not with the `verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies` trick) : the main pod and almost all its dependencies contain static libraries, and everything works perfectly along with Swift pods. Exemple with [Google/SignIn](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/Google/1.3.2/Google.podspec.json) which depends on Google/Core (vendored_libraries: Libraries/libGGLCore.a) and [GoogleSignIn](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/Google/1.3.2/Google.podspec.json) (vendored_libraries: Libraries/libSignIn.a).

Any idea of what I can do to make my pods compatible with the `use_framework!` option ?

Thank you all,

Cheers,

Tom

Comment: Hey Tom,
I am also fighting with this... And honestly I don't have a clue right now.
What I was wondering about: Are you sure, that Google did the trick? I assume that GoogleSignIn is a static library written in Objective-C. So they -correct me if I get that wrong- do not have to use "use_framework!" at all...

Comment: Yeah, but I assume, that GoogleSignIn is static as well...

Comment: Google/SignIn pod depends on Google/Core pod and GoogleSignIn pod which both contain only static libraries (.a executables) and headers. Basically same as my pods. If you make a podfile with the Google/SignIn pod, a swift pod (Alamofire for example), and the `use_framework!` option, the _pod install_ works perfectly fine. If I do the same with my pod instead of Google/SignIn, I have the "transitive dependencies" error... Can't figure out what they did :/

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3701), but don't precisely understand and can't make it work...

Comment: Ah, ok. Now I got your point. I have read it to, but unfortunately I also don't it...

Answer (score 3):

I think I found a hack for my problem. This is quite weird, but I'd say it's clean enough to use it in production ;)

I found it [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3701). The idea is simply to include a source file (even an empty one) in your source_files list inside your podspec.

Basically, the source section of my podspec looks like this :

```
s.source_files = "myLib/Empty.m", "myLib/Headers/*.h"
s.vendored_libraries  = "myLib/myLib.a"
```

The only modification I made is to add "myLib/Empty.m" in the source files (Empty.m is strictly empty). Without it, I systematically have the *transitive dependencies* error when I *pod install*. With it, *pod install* works fine. It worked for me with both Cocoapods 0.0.39 and 1.0.0.beta.4.

Well, looks like it's a *not so dirty* solution, but I'm not sure it'll work in every case. And it's no good news about the cleanliness of Cocoapods...

As I mentionned in comments earlier, Google seems to have found a cleaner solution. So if anybody have an idea of the real clean solution, please share !

Cheers,

Tom

PS : I think I'll name the file *DirtyCocoapodHack.m* instead of *Empty.m*, sure they'll love it in the dev team ;)